# How can i enable save as draft button email using android coding?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm developing one application.  In my application, send mail with attachment image using Intent.  hat is working fine, but save as draft button disable in mail application, I want to enable save as draft button for every mail.

Thanks

Comment: Its really unclear what you are doing.  Are you creating a new application,, in which you want to have a save draft button?  Or are you trying to alter the behavior of the mail application?

Comment: @Mayra Thanks for reply,No i am not alter the behavior of the mail application,Normally we want to email,we are using intent,so we got default email application by our configure email ,that email,i want to enable save as draft button for every mail,How will i do?

Comment: You are using an intent to open the default email application.  You want the save as draft button to be enabled in the default email application, when you open it with your intent?

Comment: @Mayra,correct,i want the save as draft button to enabled in the default email application ,when i open.

Comment: I doubt there is a way to do that via an intent.  Presumably the mail program has some logic it uses to decide if there is a draft to be saved.  If it doesn't think there is anything to be saved, or it has already been saved, then the button is disabled.